# Elasticsearch : Snapshots not executed automatically (cron schedule issue)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, snapshot

I've changed the schedule of my managed snapshot policy. By default, the cron is each 30 minutes, and I wanted just one per day. Since... the snapshots are not executed automatically...

I've putted back the previous configuration but it doesn't fixed the problem :/

There's no recent failure (last failure is Feb 03, 2022 10:30 AM).
BUT ! I'm able to manually take a snapshot. It's only the cron that is not working.

My deployment is at version 7.17.1, this is the json config returned by GET https://ES.HOST/_slm/policy/ :

```json
{
    "cloud-snapshot-policy": {
        "version": 10,
        "modified_date_millis": 1648205967792,
        "policy": {
            "name": "<cloud-snapshot-{now/d}>",
            "schedule": "0 */30 * * * ?",
            "repository": "found-snapshots",
            "config": {
                "partial": true
            },
            "retention": {
                "expire_after": "259200s",
                "min_count": 10,
                "max_count": 100
            }
        },
        "last_success": {
            "snapshot_name": "cloud-snapshot-2022.03.28-7bsk_rtkt7klcmre3yghtq",
            "start_time": 1648449376402,
            "time": 1648451047195
        },
        "last_failure": {
            "snapshot_name": "cloud-snapshot-2022.02.03-yyl4pcwfqvynla9v7noqgg",
            "time": 1643880630250
        },
        "next_execution_millis": 1648458000000,
        "stats": {
            "policy": "cloud-snapshot-policy",
            "snapshots_taken": 23346,
            "snapshots_failed": 230,
            "snapshots_deleted": 23214,
            "snapshot_deletion_failures": 119
        }
    }
}
```

My deployment is managed on Elastic Cloud, using Azure.

I've taken a snapshot manually 2 hours ago and, as you can see, a snapshot should have been executed 3 minutes ago but doesn't appear in my found-snapshots reposity (even in the logs, there's nothing...)

[image]

So it's "just" the cron schedule that needs to be fixed... Any suggestion ?

Thanks !

Comment: The cron expression is perfectly valid according to [the [`elasticsearch-croneval`] tool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/elasticsearch-croneval.html) and resolves to every 30 minutes...  it's weird to see "3 minutes **ago**" for the **next** snapshot, though

Answer (score 1):

Well...

POST https://ES.HOST/_slm/stop

then...

POST https://ES.HOST/_slm/start

and the cron schedule work again !

Thanks to this resource : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-lifecycle-management-api.html